# How to integrate $\frac{1}{x^4\sqrt{(x^2+3)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

can any one help me please

how to integrate this $\frac{1}{x^4\sqrt{(x^2+3)}}$  ?
By trigonometric 
Thanks all

Comment: Why don't you follow mentioned in the previous question :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Comment: @lab thank you for this link but I already studied it in my book, and I thought there is an easier way to solve it instead x=(3)^(1/2) tanu

Comment: Why didn't you ask that question more precisely? Then I wouldn't took my time to use the integration you already knew.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\int \frac{1}{x^4\sqrt{x^2+3}}$ and substitute $x=\sqrt(3) \tan(u)$ and $dx=\sqrt{3} sec^2(u) \: du$.

With $\sqrt{x^2+3}=\sqrt{3 \tan^2(u)+3}=\sqrt{3} \sec(u)$ and $u=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt 3}\right)$ you'll get

$$\int \frac{1}{(x^4(x^2+3)^(1/2))}=\int \frac 1 9 \cot^3(u) \csc(u) \; du=\frac 1 9 \int \cot^3(u) \csc(u) \; du$$

Now use identity  $\cot^2(u)=\csc^2(u)-1$:
$$\frac 1 9 \int \cot^3(u) \csc(u) \; du = \frac 1 9 \int \cot(u) \csc(u) (\csc^2(u)-1)) \; du$$

2nd substitution for integrand $\cot(u)\csc(u)(\csc^2(u)-1)$: $s=\csc(u)$ and $ds=-(\cot(u)\csc(u)) \; du$:

$$\frac 1 9 \int \cot(u) \csc(u) (\csc^2(u)-1)) \; du=-\frac 1 9 \int (s^2-1) \; ds=\frac 1 9 \int 1 \; ds - \frac 1 9 \int s^2 \; ds$$
Integrate:
$$-\frac 1 9 \int (s^2-1) \; ds=\frac 1 9 \int 1 \; ds - \frac 1 9 \int s^2 \; ds = \left[\frac s 9\right] - \left[ \frac{s^3}{27} \right]+C$$

Substitute back $s=\csc(u)$

$$\frac s 9 -  \frac{s^3}{27} = \frac{\csc(u)}{9}-\frac{\csc^3(u)}{27} +C$$

Substitute back $u=\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt 3} \right)$

$$\frac{\csc(u)}{9}-\frac{\csc^3(u)}{27} +C = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}(2x^2-3)}{27x^3}+C$$

Where

- $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$
- $\csc(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$
- $\cot(x)= \frac{1}{\tan(x)}=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$